# Can we use Mahalanobis distance to match one sentence with many other sentences and how?

Tags: correlation

suppose we have a stream of sentences and we need to compare each new sentence with previously received ones . For example , with sentences received in last 30 minutes. What is the best method to do that ?  can we use  Mahalanobis distance for this ? How ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably *can* (see the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21214/mahalanobis-distance-as-measure-of-dissimilarity-between-strings-sequences)), but depending on your application, I'm not sure that you *should*. For whatever you're doing, is there a useful interpretation of the Mahalanobis distance between two strings?

There are other measures of string similarity which might be more appropriate. For example, there are ["edit distances"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which measures the number of insertions/deletions/substitutions needed to turn one string into another. I think that there are even language- and device-specific cost functions available, if you're trying to correct for typos or something. This is a decent, if somewhat old, review of string-matching techniques [Navarro (2001)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/375360.375365). Note that most of these are pairwise and moderately computationally intensive. If you wanted to compare a new string to collection of other strings, you could turn it into a nearest-neighbor problem.

In general, these methods are only going to work for lexicographically similar strings: "Last night, I saw the cat" vs. "Last night, I saw the hat". If you're trying to detect strings which mean similar things ("I saw the cat last night" vs. "Last night, I saw a kitty"), then you're essentially tackling two or three unsolved problems :-) Get a good language processing textbook and good luck!